# How to write a regular expression to match the 3rd octet of an IP address

Tags: regex, string, replace, ip-address

I need to update the third octacte of a CIDR range (IP) in the following format.

```
10.150.0.0/27
```

I would like to match the third octet only so that I can replace it. In this case that would be the first 0 from the left.

Comment: Why not parse the CIDR and modify the IP  so you know it's valid, rather than mangling strings?

Comment: Please, add a language you want to use for the replacement. You used both [tag:java] and [tag:go] - which of them do you use?

Comment: Split on dot, modify arr[2], then join with dot.

Comment: I require this for go.which is rg2

Answer (score 3):

You can use positive lookahead to achieve that:

```
[0-9]+(?=\.[0-9]+\/)
```

Check out [this example](https://regex101.com/r/mMFvLO/1).

Comment: This one works just as expected in the link provided for the example but fails when used with go as it does not like the question mark,

Answer (score 2):

`\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(\d{1,3})\.\d{1,3}\/\d+` will capture the third section in that sequence. You can use `regex.replace` to replace it with something else.

If you're just wanting that specific IP then it's easier.
`10\.150\.(\d+)\.0\/27`

Answer (score 2):

the following regex pattern matches up to 3 digits from 0 through 9, for 4 octects, and includes the mask at the end. The parenthesis (capture group) around the third octect is what you're after.

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.([0-9]{1,3})\.[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,2}
```

or more shorthand

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(\d{1,3})\.\d{1,3}/\d{1,2}
```

in Java, you will want to do something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.([0-9]{1,3})\.[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]{1,2}";
Matcher matcher = pattern.match("yourIPAddressHere") 
while (matcher.find()) {
    String thirdOctet = matcher.group(0); <--- the number of the matching group
}
```

From there you can use a String.replace or whatever you feel like to modify the original ip. Hope this helps!

Comment: You have to escape the dot or it will match any character.

Comment: fixed. Original regex assumed only a correctly formed ipv4 with subnet cidr mask was being passed, but if you were searching within a string and wanted to match the periods specifically, yes, you'd need to escape them.